# Standard keyboard shortcut for moving items in a list?

Tags: winapi, listview, keyboard-shortcuts

For my Windows application I'm currently looking for a standard (or at least widely used) keyboard shortcut for moving items in a Win32 listview. I've looked at MSDN's recommendations [Guidelines for Keyboard User Interface Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971323.aspx#atg_keyboardshortcuts_assigning_shortcut_keys) but unfortunately, the topic isn't addressed there.

I'm thinking about <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> for moving to bottom/top) but was wondering whether there are any quasi-standard keyboard shortcuts for this task.

Comment: Ctrl+<Arrow (up|down)> was my first thought.

Comment: Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down are used to move the focus to the next item in a Win32 listview.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, Google Tasks uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to move items in the list up and down.

If there isn't a defined standard then just have a tool-tip or some help text available to the user in your application?

Comment: Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down are used to move the focus to the next item in a Win32 listview.

I'm looking for a quasi-standard (i.e., a solution that is widely used) to improve overall experience also across applications.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> feels natural and would probably be the first combination your users try, but these should only work when your `ListView` has focus. Probably hook on to the `ListView`'s own `KeyDown` event?

Also include a small `Label` near the listview telling users that:

> Ctrl+Up/Down moves items Up/Down.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> could be useful from the point of view that it makes literal sense. "Shift Up" sounds similar to "Move Up". I remember a graphic program that used the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + ArrowKey combo to move objects around quickly, in a few days it became natural to use those combos.

Lastly, consider simply <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>, which would be very easy to use, but should only work when your `ListView` has focus. It sounds radical but seems to be usable since nobody uses the Up/Down arrows keys when typing, though they may use Left/Right to move the typing cursor.

Comment: While it feels natural, it would break the standard behaviour of a Win32 listview.

Comment: Why would it break standards?

Comment: Ctrl+Up/Down are used to move the focus rectangle from one item to another.

Comment: Shift+Up/Down is used for extending the selection and Up/Down for navigation.

Comment: Then go with Ctrl+key since modifying focus via the keyboard is not too important IMO, people can easily use the more popular shortcut, TAB.

Comment: @Jenko: TAB moves focus from one control to another, not between items in a list. Modifying focus via keyboard is pretty important for accessibility; not everyone can or prefers to use a mouse for all interaction.

Comment: While Ctrl+Arrow and Shift+Arrow have other meanings, they may not necessarily be a conflict in your case: Ctrl+Arrow is used to move the focus around so you can select _additional_ items with the spacebar;and Shift+Arrow also allows you to select _additional_ contiguous items - its sounds like your case may not care about or use multiple or even single selection at all; you may be only moving the focused item around. In which case using Shift or Control should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Office combination to do this Alt + Shift + ↑